# In bash, how to temporarily suspend, mostly called "out-comment", a chunk of command lines with line continuation backslashes?

Tags: bash, shell

In order to make my work easier, I am writing a long bash script with the aim to be run once after reboot or at beginning of a working cycle or when trying another operating system, when no bash_history files are available. It should fill the history list with many complicated commands, one-liners, like if I had used them hours before.

But because these commands should not really be run in that moment, I put them into the history list by commands like:

```
history -s ': # echo "== do not sleep"'
```

To use both, the colon ":" and the hash character "#", has some advanteges experienced in many years but forgotten in the moment.

So I can search in the history, remove the comment token ": # " at beginning of line and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.

I know that I could use other methods to do this, but this way works very fine, except for complicated long commands, one-liners, e.g. which contain line continuations with backslashes or other specials.

In other computer languages, e.g. C, Perl, there are ways to “out-comment” code.

Often one can emulate such things in bash somehow to get the same result.

Does someone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution

as of 02.08.2022:

Now I have a working solution and can present it here (my former trials failed because of a typo):

```
read -r -d "" WEx <<EOT
: # echo "do not sleep \
in \
many \
lines"
EOT

history -s "$WEx"
```

The delimiter EOT may be in double quotes or not. The difference is:

If in double quotes this is stored in the history list in multiple history lines, but if not in double quotes then in a single history line.

In order the whole chunk to stay in effect as out-commented until ": # " at beginning  of history line is not removed, the delimiter must not be in double quotes.

Important to note:

shopt option cmdhist
is set (default)

and

shopt option lithist
is not set

Regards

antonhdidh